# React-Native: App crashes when Pushwoosh notification is received

Tags: react-native, pushwoosh

I follow all the steps listed here: https://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/deep-linking and here https://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/androidmanifestxml-modifications#deep-linking to add **PushWoosh** notifications to my app.

The notification is correctly showed in the status bar, but every time a push is received the app crashes.

The emulator show an alert saying: **MY_APP_NAME has stopped** and the following error is logged in Crashalytics:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to instantiate
>   service com.pushwoosh.PushFcmIntentService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.pushwoosh.PushFcmIntentService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/MY_APP_PACKAGE/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/MY_APP_PACKAGE/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/MY_APP_PACKAGE/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /product/lib]]

I know it crashes in my test device too because is registered in Crashalytics as well.

I tried removing the **DeviceEventEmitter** listeners and having the minimal configuration, but nothing fixes the error.

```
Pushwoosh.init({ 
    "pw_appid" : "APP_ID" , 
    "project_number" : "PROJECT_NUMBER" 
  });
Pushwoosh.register();
```

Does anyone have any idea about that **com.pushwoosh.PushFcmIntentService** missing class?

I have intalled the latest versión of the plugin:

```
"pushwoosh-react-native-plugin": "^5.5.3"
```

Comment: Did you edit the build.gradle file inside the android folder like mentioned in the linked documentation? [link](https://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/react-native-plugin)

Comment: Yes, but the error exists even before I added the deep linking feature.